# How to set default permission to /opt/ directory

Tags: ubuntu

I have set "chmod -R 777 . /opt/" and made the directory writable. However, this gave error to my phpmyadmin (inside /opt/lampp/) which should not be writable.

Can someone help me to reset to default permission of the /opt/ directory?

Great Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `/opt` directory has permissions `drwxr-xr-x` with owner `root:root`. You can set this as follows

```
sudo chown root:root /opt
sudo chmod 0755 /opt
```

If you have changed the permissions of sub-directories, then the solution is not generic. Though my subdirectories also have same permissions, it can be different. `-R` parameter can do this recursively.

```
sudo chown -R root:root /opt
sudo chmod -R 0755 /opt
```

Comment: I did try but no luck, I just reinstalled Ubuntu on my machine. Thanks a lot!